# error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, exception

here is the code .
i want to make a calcuclate which can add nos inputted by user in single lines.

```
package demo;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
   int num[]=new int[10];
    String input;
    input=cin.nextLine();
    int a=0,length=input.length();
    for(int r=0;r<10;r++){ 
        for(int b=a;b<=length;b++){ char char_at=input.charAt(b);
         if(char_at=='+'){String xxx=input.substring(a,b);
         int q=Integer.parseInt(xxx);
         num[r]=q;
         a=b;
         }
       }}
    int sum=0; 
    for(int j=0;j<=10;j++){sum=sum+num[j];}
    System.out.println("sum="+sum);
    }}
```

Comment: Which line threw the exception? Have you tried debugging it? Note that if you spread your code out a bit more with whitespace/line breaks, it'll be easier to find your way around...

Comment: Check out Exception StackTrace , it is self explanatory .

Comment: int a=0,length=input.length()-2; should work

Answer (score 1):

You have these problems

1. always assume you are adding 10 numbers
2. not change the value of r to add a new number
3. never add the last number

This solve your problem (adds a max of 10 numbers):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num[]=new int[10];
    String input;
    input=cin.nextLine();

    int a=0,length=input.length();

    int r=0;
    for(int b=a;b<length;b++)
    {
        char char_at=input.charAt(b);
        if(char_at=='+')
        {
            String xxx=input.substring(a,b);
            int q=Integer.parseInt(xxx);
            num[r++]=q;
            a=b;
        }
    }
    String xxx=input.substring(a,length);
    int q=Integer.parseInt(xxx);
    num[r]=q;

    int sum=0; 
    for(int j=0;j<=r;j++)
        sum=sum+num[j];
    System.out.println("sum="+sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ***Indexing*** in Java is `0 Based`

So if the length of String is 10 you are actually accesing 11th Index that is why this Exception is coming

So Replace this

```
for(int b=a;b<=length;b++){
```

with this

```
for(int b=a;b<length;b++){
```

Comment: getting this ----  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at demo.Demo.main(Demo.java:13)